# OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler equivalent for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I can opt into receiving a push notification in Android, but on IOS I can't find an equivalent way to do the same.

In android I can override:

```
@Override
public void remoteNotificationReceived(Context context, OSNotificationReceivedEvent notificationReceivedEvent) {
    OSNotification notification = notificationReceivedEvent.getNotification();
    notificationReceivedEvent.complete(notification);
    <-- I can do something with the notification data here.
}
```

How can I do the same in iOS?

I'm using onesignal, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS the user has to opt in to receive notifications. I would suggest following a tutorial for the whole process. [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/11395893-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started) is a tutorial from Ray Wenderlich.

Assuming you have done all of the setup, the code you are looking for is inside the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate. Specifically,

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
optional func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
optional func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async
```

depending on if you want async or closures.